# image as background in newsletter .net

Tags: html, outlook

Have problem displaying a picture in my newsletter. It displays perfect in browsers but in e.x outlook the td Style="background tag dosent work at all.

Code:

```
<td colspan="2" width="100%" valign="top" style="background: #ffffff
url('/image/image.png') no-repeat center bottom; width:100%; padding-bottom: 70px;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="718" style="background-
color:#FFF;">
```

i tried put in a <%=Page.ResolveUrl but no effect...im starting to suspect that outlook does not support this tag at all, not even the background colors gets displayed in the mail.

So my question is there any way to keep the background tag in the td? Do i need to have it as an img tag :(?

Comment: Do you think any mail system would understand `url('/image/image.png')`? That has to be an absolute url

Comment: Where does Outlook supposed to get the image from? Either use absolute URL or embed the image with email

Comment: What in this is an asp.net issue? YOu basically has a HTML issue in OUTLOOK rendering and totally off tagging.

Comment: Alright guess you guys are right chill my first post here xP...just trying to understand someone elses code but then I know thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly Outlook doesn't support background-image.  Have a look at this:

http://i3.campaignmonitor.com/assets/files/css/campaign-monitor-guide-to-css-in-email-may-2014.pdf?ver=2286&_ga=1.34157217.10778339.1399389464

And it lists most of what each client does and doesn't support.  You will need an absolute URL too